# Links not working in IE8 when Application accessed with Fully Qualified Domain name

Tags: internet-explorer, user-interface

My application works perfectly fine in Firefox and Chrome. But In case of IE8, everything is fine if I access the application using localhost or the IPAddress. But when I access the Application with the Fully Qualified Domain Name(Computer Name), then some of the links on the page do not work. They are not recognized as links at all. Has anybody experienced a similar issue?

Thanks,
Leela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because of some overlapping divs. Fixed it. But still do not understand why it works with ipconfig and gives problem only with the domain name